# Use Junction or symbolic link to "rename" NTFS directory

Tags: windows, ntfs, symbolic-link, junction

I was wondering (indeed it would be very useful) if it is possible to use NTFS Junction, symbolic link or something like that to use an alias for some directory, and at the same time to hide the original one. I mean, just like Windows' localized  default dirs like Program Files, Users and others.

In my case, there's a default junction for Program Files called "Arquivos de Programas". The original Program Files isn't listed at Explorer, and it also doesn't have any attributes other than read only.

How does Microsoft do that? I want to do something like that with my own directories. is this possible?

Comment: As far as I know, the folder you see in Explorer is the real "Program Files", but Explorer shows the translated name obtained with SHGet­Localized­Name. The junction is there just for compatibility in some other situations (not sure which ones) and has some weird permission settings to be hidden and not readable (I couldn't find all the necessary technical details to promote this to a full answer).